# i need in select box option like option1 (10)

Tags: html

I want to put a span / div tag inside an <option>. Is it possible to do or anyone ever find this kind of problem?  Here is the code:

```
<option>
  <span class="bla1">Bla...bla....</span>
  <span class="bla2">Bla...bla....</span>
  <span class="bla3">Bla...bla....</span>
</option>
```

Comment: Could you give us more information about your problem? I can't understand what are you asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you´re trying to specify some kind of detail for each option.

something like this:

`Language Courses:`

```
< select>

    < option>English < span>Basic</ span>< span>Advanced</ span>< span>Native</ span></ option> 

    < option>Spanish < span>Basic</ span>< span>Advanced</ span>< span>Native</ span></ option> 

    ... etc

</ select>
```

if that´s the case, maybe you want to use a `select` element for the main selection, and another one for the subselection, possibly using javascript to dynamically change the suboptions if required

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not complete. Inside of ??(what) Anyways, you can use input type of buttonand then followed by span.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no problem inserting a div/span tag inside your select/option tag.
Try it yourshelf :)